# IE10 anchor tag z-index issue

Tags: html, css

In IE 10, I have a relatively positioned wrapper div with some content (an image / text). Inside of that div is an absolutely positioned anchor tag which is positioned to "cover" the entire wrapper div. It has a z-index set. So the entire area inside the wrapper div should be clickable. However, only the areas in the wrapper div that don't have content are clickable. The entire wrapper div is clickable in all other browsers except for IE 10. Here is a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/NUyhF/3/. Help?

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="imgWrapper">
        <img src="http://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo4w.png" />
    </div>
    <p>Here is some text</p>
    <a href="#"></a>
</div>

.wrapper { position : relative; width: 500px; height: 300px; }
.wrapper a { position: absolute; top: 0px; width: 500px; height: 300px; z-index: 2; }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found this to be an annoying trait of IE for some time, to solve it I had to make a transparent image and use it as the background of the anchor tag:

```
background:url(transparent1x1.gif) repeat;
```

http://jsfiddle.net/NUyhF/6/

Comment: Yes, that works. But it does not have to be a background image (=extra resource to load) – simply using `background:rgba(0,0,0,0);` works as well.

Answer (score 3):

It is now semantically correct to wrap block level elements in an anchor tag (using the html5 doctype).  I would suggest amending your markup to this.

**HTML**

```
<a href="#">
    <div class="imgWrapper">
        <img src="http://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo4w.png" />
    </div>
    <p>Here is some text</p>
</a>
```

Comment: Thank you, but unfortunately I must support legacy browsers.

Comment: This will work fine on older browsers.  I support down to ie7 and have no problems with it.

Comment: OK - You said "HTML5 allows." I wish I could accept both answers! However, the JSFiddle was a simplified version of the html I actually had in there, so it was easier for me to just use the the transparent color background.